# while working with gspread-pandas module, I want to change default_dir of the module

Tags: python, pandas

```
import json
from os import path, makedirs

_default_dir = path.expanduser('~/.config/gspread_pandas')
_default_file = 'google_secret.json'

def ensure_path(pth):
    if not path.exists(pth):
        makedirs(pth)
```

hi, I'm currently working on data collection via selenium and pandas to parse the data and edit it with pandas to send the data to google spread

however, while I'm working on gspread-pandas module, the module needs to put google_secret json file to '~/.config/gspread_pandas'. which is fixed location as described in the link below
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gspread-pandas/0.15.1

I want to make some function to set the custom location to achieve independent working app environment.

for example, I want to locate the file to here

```
default_folder = os.getcwd()
```

the default_folder will be where my project is located(the same folder)

what can I do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the source  https://github.com/aiguofer/gspread-pandas/blob/master/gspread_pandas/conf.py you can notice, that you can create your own config and pass it to Spread object constructor. 
But yes, this part is really badly documented.

So, this code works well for me:

```
from gspread_pandas import Spread, conf
c = conf.get_config('[Your Path]', '[Your filename]')
spread = Spread('username', 'spreadname', config=c)
```

Comment: thankyou So much for your kind answer, I just modified the module

from here
_default_dir = path.expanduser('~/.config/gspread_pandas')
to here
import os
_default_dir = path.expanduser('os.getcwd())

it also worked fine for me

Comment: Cool to see there's some questions on gspread_pandas here :) Indeed @lazarev-ivan's answer is the correct way for doing this. I'll add some documentation for this, and maybe even add a way to change the default directory with an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this.  It really should be documented better.  I was getting so frustrated trying to get this to work with `heroku`, but it worked perfectly.  I had to change to the following:

```
c = gspread_pandas.conf.get_config('/app/', 'google_secret.json')
spread = gspread_pandas.Spread('google_sheet_key_here_that_is_a_long_string', config=c)
```